# How to change the pair of a changed HTML tag in Vim?

Tags: vim, html

How can I configure Vim so that when I change one member of a matching pair of HTML tags, the other is automatically changed to match?

For example: given `<span>content</span>`, I want to change `<span>` to `<div>`, and then the closing `</span>` automatically changes to `</div>`. Optimally this would happen upon returning from insert mode to normal mode, but it would be OK if I had to hit a special keybinding to make this happen.

Answer (score 30):

The excellent [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) makes this simple — with the cursor anywhere within the tag you want to change, in normal mode, type `cst<div>` (`c`hange `s`urrounding `t`ag to `<div>`). The tag name will be changed to "div" in both the opening and closing tag, and you'll be back in normal mode.

Answer (score 4):

Here are few steps:

1. Place your cursor on the first tag.
2. Select outer html code by pressing: <kbd>v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>.
3. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit visual mode and type:

   ```
   :'<,'<s/span/div/
   :'>,'>s/span/div/
   ```

   <sup>Note that `:'>,'>s/span/div/` won't work correctly if there are two occurrences of the same closing tag in the same line, as it'll always change the first one. To fix it, use: `:'>,'>s/.*\zsspan/div/` instead. See: [How to change last occurrence of the string in the line?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2103/467)</sup>

Related:

- [How to jump between matching HTML/XML tags?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/780/467) at Vim SE

Comment: Does entering visual mode do anything, once you've exited it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question. In the visual mode you're selecting the outer html for the given HTML tags, so substitution will only affect the selected region.

Comment: When I tried this, it looked like pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> exited visual mode *entirely*, so that the substitution would have effected any other region; nothing remained highlighted after pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> .

Comment: @Pureferret The ranges from the 3. step should use the last selected region.

Comment: This is a terrible thing!  It must change a closing tag on the fly during editting matching tag

Comment: Does not seem ergonomic. So much keystrokes (time) for such a simple operation.

Answer (score 3):

The Vim [tagalong](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/tagalong.vim) plugin can do this:

[image: Vim tagalong]

Answer (score 0):

With the [SwapIt - Extensible keyword swapper](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2294), you can define tag groups that can then be toggled via `<C-a>` / `<C-x>`. For example, in `~/.vim/ftplugin/html_swapit.vim`:

```
SwapList layout p div span
```

---

If you have both start and end tag on the same line (and there's only one of that type), you can edit both via my [ChangeGlobally plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4321).

---

There are also several "multicursor" plugins, which allow you to mark certain words and edit them all at once.